# Как выводить ошибку с сервера через middleware RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, типы

**Суть проблемы: я хочу выводить ошибки через middleware rtk, для этого создал rtkQueryErrorLogger согласно документации самого rtk [Тык](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling) но вместо текста ошибки с сервера оно выводит только статус самого запроса "Rejected"e**

store.ts

```
import { configureStore, isRejectedWithValue, Middleware, MiddlewareAPI } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import authSlice from '../slices/auth-slice'
import { authApi } from '../api/auth-api/auth-api'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'

export const rtkQueryErrorLogger: Middleware =
  (api: MiddlewareAPI) => (next) => (action) => {
    // RTK Query uses `createAsyncThunk` from redux-toolkit under the hood, so we're able to utilize these matchers!
    if (isRejectedWithValue(action)) {
      console.warn('We got a rejected action!')
      toast.error(
        'data' in action.error
            ? (action.error.data as { message: string }).message
            : action.error.message,
      )
    }

    return next(action)
  }

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [authApi.reducerPath]: authApi.reducer,
        auth: authSlice
    },
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(authApi.middleware).concat(rtkQueryErrorLogger)

})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
```

auth-api-slice.ts

```
import { fetchUser, login, refreshToken } from "../../slices/auth-slice";
import { IUser, IUserReq } from "../../types/types";
import { authApi } from "./auth-api";

export const authApiSlice = authApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: builder => ({
        register: builder.mutation<IUser, IUserReq>({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: `auth/register`,
                method: 'POST',
                body
            })
        }),
        login: builder.mutation<string, IUserReq>({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: `/auth/login`,
                method: 'POST',
                body
            }),
            async onQueryStarted(arg, api) {
                try {
                    const { data } = await api.queryFulfilled
                    api.dispatch(login(data))
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            }
        }),
        refreshToken: builder.query<string, void>({
            query: () => `auth/refresh`,
            async onQueryStarted(arg, api) {
                try {
                    const { data } = await api.queryFulfilled
                    api.dispatch(refreshToken(data))
                } catch (err) {
                    localStorage.removeItem('token')
                }
            }
        }),
        fetchUser: builder.query<IUser, void>({
            query: () => `auth/profile`,
            async onQueryStarted(arg, api) {
                const { data } = await api.queryFulfilled
                api.dispatch(fetchUser(data))
            }
        })
    })
})


export const { useLoginMutation, useRegisterMutation, useFetchUserQuery, useRefreshTokenQuery } = authApiSlice
```

auth-api.ts

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import type {
  BaseQueryFn,
  FetchArgs,
  FetchBaseQueryError,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import { RootState } from '../../store/store'
import { logout, refreshToken } from '../../slices/auth-slice'


const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
  credentials: 'include',
  prepareHeaders: (headers, api) => {
    const token = (api.getState() as RootState).auth.token
    if (token) {
      headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    }

    return headers
  }
})


const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
  if (result.error && result.error.status === 401) {
    const refreshResult = await baseQuery('auth/refresh', api, extraOptions)
    if (refreshResult.data) {
      api.dispatch(refreshToken(refreshResult.data))
      result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('token')
      api.dispatch(logout())
    }
  }
  return result
}


export const authApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  endpoints: builder => ({}),
})
```

SignIn.ts

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Box, Button, TextField, Typography, useTheme } from '@mui/material'
import { Controller, SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { formBodyProps, submitButtonProps } from '../features-SignIn/styles/styles';
import { formSchema } from '../features-SignIn/schema/schema';
import { IUserReq, useAppDispatch, useLoginMutation } from '@diary-app/shared';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

export const SignIn: React.FC = () => {

  const theme = useTheme()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [login, { error, isError }] = useLoginMutation()
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
  const { control, handleSubmit, reset, formState: { errors } } = useForm<IUserReq>({
    mode: 'onChange',
    resolver: yupResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    }
  })

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IUserReq> = async (data) => {
    const res = await login(data).unwrap()
      .then(res => {
        navigate('/')
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default }}
      width='100vw'
      height='100vh'
      display='flex'
      justifyContent='center'
      alignItems='center'
    >
      <Box
        sx={formBodyProps}
        display='flex'
        justifyContent='center'
        alignItems='center'
        flexDirection='column'
      >
        <Typography mb='5%' variant='h2'>Sign In</Typography>
        <Box
          width='100%'
          rowGap={3}
          component='form'
          display='flex'
          flexDirection='column'
          justifyContent='center'
          alignItems='center'
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        >
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name='username'
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextField
                autoComplete='true'
                fullWidth
                color='secondary'
                label='Username'
                onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e)}
                value={field.value}
                error={!!errors.username}
                helperText={errors.username?.message}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name='password'
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextField
                autoComplete='true'
                fullWidth
                color='secondary'
                label='Password'
                type='password'
                error={!!errors.password}
                onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e)}
                value={field.value}
                helperText={errors.password?.message}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Button type='submit' color="secondary" variant="outlined" sx={submitButtonProps}>Sign Ip</Button>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box >
  )
}
```

[image: 1]